# css responsive Ranking and change of positions

Tags: css

I am trying to change the div positions when change page screen. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/yOwLNz?editors=1100)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there are two column green and red. I want to change this green and red div ranking and positioning. How can i do that anyone can help me here ?

Need to be like this after :

```
@media screen and (max-width:1210px) {
   .app-one { 
       /* app-one is green div */
      /*need to come to the BOTTOM. and width:100%;*/
   }
   .app-two {
     /* app-two is red div */
     /* need to come to the TOP. and width:100%; */
   }
}
```

Comment: if you remove the flex properties then you can use the float and do it easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the direction of your flexbox container:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1210px) {
   .ChWrP{
      flex-direction: column-reverse;   
   } 
   .ChWrP > div { 
      width: 100%;  
   } 
}
```

> [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKbaLL)

Comment: Sure you deserved it ;) . Thanks